# variable php return undefined in ajax (send back undefined to ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Actually, I looking solution to the problem, but I can't solve this problem. In this Ajax, returns the `undefined` in the alert.

PHP function:

```
function myfunc(){
    $arr = array(
        'var' => 'hello',
    );
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myfunc', 'myfunc');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfunc', 'myfunc');
```

and jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>",
            dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    action : 'myfunc',
                },
                success: function(data,textStatus) {
                    alert(data.var);
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

also, I tried `alert(data);`, but it returns 0.

Comment: How are you calling the AJAX function?

Comment: with Clicking on div : $("#doaction").click(function(){   $.ajax({...});   });

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in your browser's console? Based on what I see here you're not calling the AJAX function at all.

Comment: actually the php function , It was working properly. but i want to back a variable php in to ajax alert , it return Undefined or 0 ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is best practices to use wp_die() instead of exit().  See: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved . 
problem is absence "exit" in last line of function . 
thanks ..